# event.keyCode not working with help of ng-change in AngularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have restrict(even copy and paste also) number and special character in my html text field.I am using ng-change="getPatternForAlphebet($event,$index)" but not working.I am using as.

```
<input
                type="text" ng-model="paternalname"  ng-change="getPatternForAlphebet($event,$index)">
```

**Controller as**

```
$scope.getPatternForAlphebet = function(event,rowIndex){   
        if ((event.keyCode > 64 && event.keyCode < 91)||  (event.keyCode > 96 && event.keyCode < 123) {
            }else{
                event.preventDefault();
            }
    };
```

Comment: can not pass `$event` to `ng-change` directive

Comment: use `ng-copy` and `ng-paste`

Comment: can you provide in fiddle if possible.because i dont know about ng-copy function

Comment: is it possible put in ng-if,if possible please

Answer (score 0):

Try as like below by using your own custom directive

in html

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input numbers-only ng-model="numbers" type="text">
    </div>
</body>
```

in angular

```
;(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.numbers = 45;
        }])
        .directive('numbersOnly', function () {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {

                    function fromUser(text) {
                        if (text) {
                            var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                            if (transformedInput !== text) {
                                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                                ngModelCtrl.$render();
                            }
                            return transformedInput;
                        }

                        return '';
                    }

                    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
                }
            };
        });
    })();
```

you can change regular expression and the name numbersOnly which suites to your requirement. It will work for both copy pasting and typing as well